# how to scan or read a GS1 DataBar in iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, gs1-databar

I'm looking for a way to read [GS1 DataBar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1_DataBar) from an **iPhone app**.

I want to confirm that **GS1 databars** can be encoded with data like expiry date.

Is there such an app?

Are there any **opensource** barcode scanner projects that I can take advantage of to read **GS1 databar**?

***Edit for clarification:***
I apologize for making the question somewhat unclear.

- A GS1 databar can hold information like an item's expiry date or batch number unlike the conventional barcodes we can see from products these days.
- The main function of this potential application I am trying to build is to retrieve and show the data for expiry date of food products through the GS1 databar scanning.
- As for feasiblity test, I would need a databar scanner available on smartphones to be sure of the accessibility of the databars. However, according to my research, there are similar apps for the conventional barcodes, but not for the databars; I believe there are not many databars printed on products in retail stores, if that can be one of the reasons for it.
- So I would like to ask **if anyone is aware of an ongoing opensource project for making such 'databar' scanner?**

if there is one, I will be able to make a UI by reformatting the data retrieved from the databar information into a JSON. Thank you.

Comment: and reason you spam-tagged this with "Android" is what exactly?